# Running the same mixed model with different contrasts to explore different hypotheses

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, post-hoc, contrasts

I'm running the following mixed model to explore the relationship between `Condition` (3 levels; `Predicted`, `Plausible`, `Unpred/Plaus`) and `HighLow` (2 levels; `High`, `Low`) on `RT` (reaction time):

```
RT_lme<- lmer(RT ~ Condition*HighLow+(Condition|Pt_ID) + (Condition|SentNumb),
data = testing_data.df,control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

I am using dummy coding for `HighLow` and sum coding for `Condition` to explore the following:

Predicted,High-Implausible,High
Predicted,High- Plaus/unpred,high
Low-High
(Implausible,high - Predicted,high) - (Implausible,low - Predicted,low)
(plaus/unpred,high - Predicted,high) - (plaus/unpred,low - predicted, low)

The contrasts for this are

```
high=0 low=1


Predicted     1   1/3  1/3
Implausible   1   -2/3 1/3
Plaus/Unpred  1    1/3 -2/3
```

However, I am also interested in exploring
Predicted,low-Implausible,low
Predicted,low- Plaus/unpred,low
predicted,high-predicted,low

Can I run the same mixed model with different contrasts to achieve this, or is it only appropriate to conduct post-hoc comparisons?